# Jquery, loop through AJAX JSON response and append to array of element ids

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have found some similar questions but not quite exactly what I need. I am using AJAX to get the real-time status of property availability. I am getting the response to work as needed and can see the response in the console log. What I am unsure of how to do, is to iterate through the JSON response and append the information to existing element id's to show the availability.

The JSON response is set up like so: `[{status: AVAILABLE, category: 21}, {status: SOLDOUT, category: 19}]`

```
$.ajax({
  url: bta_obj.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      'action': 'get_checkfront_items',
      'arrive' : arrive,
      'depart' : depart,
      'categories' : categories,
    },
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    $(json).each(function(i,val){
      $.each(val,function(k,v){
        // here is where the magic needs to happen      
      });
    });
   },
   error: function(errorThrown){
     alert('well darn it....');
   }
 });
```

There are div id's that match the category ids. So I first need to determine if the category id matches a div id and then append the status to that div id. Hope that makes sense.

**Update**

For those who can't see past simple typos in an example JSON response, I have added the brackets that were dearly required....

Comment: Your JSON is not in a valid form. It should have been [{status: AVAILABLE, category: 21}, {status: SOLDOUT, category: 19}] to be an array of status for each category. Then you have to show what your html looks like to figure out how to plug these values.

Comment: Either you know how to iterate through it or you dont

Comment: haa haa, good luck.

Comment: Not sure if I understand but $('#' + status).text(category); should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery provides [the ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to obtain a DOM element by its ID and the [text](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method to change the DOM element innerText.

```
$(json).each(function(i,val){
  $('#'+val.category).text(val.status);
});
```

Comment: 5 stars @gosha-fighten! Thanks for that. I was attempting some other ways but was putting too much into it. I like it. Clean and simple.